# 4 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found

Tags: flutter, text

Not able to print clicked after clicking and all area from CustomBtn bracket is red underlined till the bracket closed

```
CustomBtn(
                text: "Create New Account",
                onPressed: () {
                  print("Clicked");
                },
),
```

Here is CustomBtn class it is another file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final String write;
  final void Function() onPressed;
  final bool outlineBtn;
  final bool isLoading;
  CustomBtn(this.write, this.onPressed, this.outlineBtn, this.isLoading, {Key? key} : super(key: key));



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: Container(
        height: 70.0,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 2.0,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
            12.0,
          ),
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 24.0,
          vertical: 24.0,
        ),
        child: Text(
          write ?? "text",
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am Trying and seeing from this youtube video
https://youtu.be/YPqYnM6KjZI

and here is the time where i am facing problem
at 12:50 [https://youtu.be/YPqYnM6KjZI?t=770[][2]](https://youtu.be/YPqYnM6KjZI?t=770%5B%5D%5B2%5D)

Answer (score 1):

your constructor has positional parameters and therefore are required and you have to pass values to it otherwise the compiler complains :). Either change them to named parameters and make the type nullable like so:

```
final String? write;
CustomBtn({
   this.write,

   etc...
})
```

or simply pass some values

Answer (score 1):

This is because your constructor has

```
  final String write;
  final void Function() onPressed;
  final bool outlineBtn;
  final bool isLoading;
```

so it requires to send the parameters to works.
Here you Flutter is waiting a call of your customBtn like this :

```
CustomBtn(
  write: "Create New Account",
  onPressed: () {
    print("Clicked");
  },
  outlineBtn: false,
  isLoading: false,
),
```

If you don't need to require this parameters, you can put a ? after the type in the declaration, like below.

```
  final String? write;
  final void? Function() onPressed;
  final bool? outlineBtn;
  final bool? isLoading;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just convert this line:

```
  CustomBtn(this.write, this.onPressed, this.outlineBtn, this.isLoading, {Key? key} : super(key: key));
```

to:

```
  CustomBtn({this.write, this.onPressed, this.outlineBtn, this.isLoading, Key? key} : super(key: key));
```